# Recommended KVM switches for working with three monitors and on Vista / Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, kvm-switch

Does anyone have any recommendations of KVM switches to try that (ideally) will work on Windows 7 but crucially support three monitors?

I had a Belkin one but some keys didn't work on my Dell keyboard and their technical support was horrendously lackluster. So please, if possible no Belkin!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Josh,

I'd recommend taking a look at KVMs from ATEN Technology - www.aten-usa.com.

The company sells a four-port DVI KVM switch that works with Vista and Windows 7 operating systems.

Here is link to the unit:

http://aten-usa.com/?product&cat=787&Item=CS1644

Good luck on your search!